# Is it possible to "create" css classes dynamically when declaring on html5?

Tags: html, css, class

what i mean is, is there any way to set a value for certain attribute when declaring a class like..i don´t know:

```
<div class='padding-l-10'>
  ----------------*code here*-------------------
</div>

.padding-l-X {
    padding-left: X;
}
```

so "it compiles" to my sass or css like:

```
.padding-l-10 {
    padding-left: 10;
}
```

I know we can do that with jquery or so, but directly with css and html, is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't be possible with only HTML & CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because your SASS compiles down to simple dumm CSS. It does the compilation without any knowledge of the HTML, so sadly this isn't possible.